# how to use POST to get what i choose from dropdown list in php

Tags: php

I have this program,what code can i use to post this program.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>FORM</title>
    </head>
    <form method="post" action="processform.php">
        <p><form action=""><tr  width="10%">Units:
            <select name="Select">
                <option value="select">Select</option>
                <option value="pack">Pack</option>
                <option value="carton">Carton</option>
                <option value="pieces">Pieces</option>
            <p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <input type="submit" value="send" /><br />
</form>
</body>
</html
```

Comment: Er... The HTML doesn't look valid.

Comment: Hi, Tee, and welcome to StackOverflow. Please read  careful “[How do ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)”.

Comment: Tee please mark and up-vote the answer. thanks

Comment: peoples are not interested in telling problem solved or not? wastage of effort. Deleting my answer.

Answer (score 0):

processform.php

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['Select']))
    {
        $select = $_POST['Select'];
        echo $select;
    }
?>
```